# Random Pre-login handshake fail while github workflow run

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, github-actions, .net-5

The github workflow randomly fails during tests.
This is somehow related with database handshake, but I cannot figure out what is going on.
Mostly it succeed but some time it fails by no reason. Have you noticed similar issues?

Plaftorm: .NET 5.0

```
 Starting test execution, please wait...
 TearDown failed for test fixture ET.WebApi.DatabaseAccess.Tests.Integration.DatabaseAccessSetUpFixture
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was successfully established with the server, 
 but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, 
 error: 0 - No such file or directory)
 Data:
   HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server
   HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer
   HelpLink.EvtID: 2
   HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
   HelpLink.LinkId: 20476
   ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No such file or directory TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

workflow file:

```
name: .NET Unit and Integration Testing

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  Tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ENVIRONMENT: Development
      GITHUB_WORKFLOW_CONNECTION_STRING: "Data Source=localhost;
      Uid=sa;Password=MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwd!!;Persist Security Info=True;"
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
        
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
      
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
      
    - name: Run MsSQL Server
      uses: isbang/compose-action@v1.0.0
      with:
        compose-file: ET.WebAPI.Api/docker-compose.integration-tests.yml
        
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwd!!'
      MSSQL_PID: 'Express'
```

Server setup step output:

> Run isbang/compose-action@v1.0.0   with:
> compose-file: ET.WebAPI.Api/docker-compose.integration-tests.yml   env:
> ENVIRONMENT: Development
> GITHUB_WORKFLOW_CONNECTION_STRING: Data Source=localhost;Uid=sa;***;Persist Security Info=True;
> DOTNET_ROOT: /home/runner/.dotnet Creating network "etwebapiapi_default" with the default driver Pulling mssql
> (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest)... 2019-latest: Pulling
> from mssql/server Creating etwebapiapi_mssql_1 ...  Digest:
> sha256:925bb075b5715b20c2acfbc244db857c92afbdfbaefbe27257a4b97817906bef
> Status: Downloaded newer image for
> mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest Creating
> etwebapiapi_mssql_1 ... done compose started

Test step output:

> Run dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal Build started 10/29/2021
> 07:15:31.
> 1>Project "/home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.sln" on node
> 1 (VSTest target(s)).
> 1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
> Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU". Test run for /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebApi.DatabaseAccess.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebApi.DatabaseAccess.Tests.Integration.dll
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 16.11.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
> reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... A total of 1 test files
> matched the specified pattern. Test run for
> /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.Kernel.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebAPI.Kernel.Tests.Unit.dll
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 16.11.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
> reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... A total of 1 test files
> matched the specified pattern. NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution
> started Running all tests in
> /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebApi.DatabaseAccess.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebApi.DatabaseAccess.Tests.Integration.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 3 of 3 NUnit test cases NUnit Adapter
> 3.16.1.0: Test execution started Running all tests in /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.Kernel.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebAPI.Kernel.Tests.Unit.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor converted 26 of 26 NUnit test cases   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,True)
> [16 ms]   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,False)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,False)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,False)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,False)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,null,False)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> EqualsTests(ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,ET.WebAPI.Kernel.ErrorsHandling.OperationResult,True)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> WhenFailureErrorMessageIsNullThenInvalidOperationExceptionIsThrown [10
> ms]   Passed WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorMessage [< 1
> ms]   Passed
> WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorType(BusinessLogic) [1
> ms]   Passed WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorType(Api) [<
> 1 ms]   Passed WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorType(None)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveNegativeIsProceededFlag [4 ms]
> Passed WhenProceededThenOperationResultShouldHaveEmptyErrorMessage [<
> 1 ms]   Passed WhenProceededThenOperationResultShouldHaveNoneErrorType
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> WhenProceededThenOperationResultShouldHavePositiveIsProceededFlag [< 1
> ms]   Passed
> WhenFailureErrorMessageIsNullThenInvalidOperationExceptionIsThrown [<
> 1 ms]   Passed WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorMessage [<
> 1 ms] NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test execution complete   Passed
> WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorType(BusinessLogic) [< 1
> ms]   Passed WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorType(Api) [<
> 1 ms]   Passed WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveErrorType(None)
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> WhenFailureThenOperationResultShouldHaveNegativeIsProceededFlag [< 1
> ms]   Passed
> WhenProceededThenOperationResultShouldHaveEmptyErrorMessage [< 1 ms]
> Passed WhenProceededThenOperationResultShouldHaveNoneErrorType [< 1
> ms]   Passed
> WhenProceededThenOperationResultShouldHavePositiveIsProceededFlag [< 1
> ms]   Passed WhenProceededThenOperationResultValueShouldHaveValue [< 1
> ms]
>
> Test Run Successful. Total tests: 26
> Passed: 26  Total time: 2.4190 Seconds Test run for /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.BusinessLogic.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebAPI.BusinessLogic.Tests.Unit.dll
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 16.11.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
> reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... A total of 1 test files
> matched the specified pattern. TearDown failed for test fixture
> ET.WebApi.DatabaseAccess.Tests.Integration.DatabaseAccessSetUpFixture
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was successfully
> established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
> pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such file
> or directory) Data:   HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server
> HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer   HelpLink.EvtID: 2
> HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
> HelpLink.LinkId: 20476   ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception :
> No such file or directory TearDown : System.NullReferenceException :
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NUnit Adapter
> 3.17.0.0: Test execution complete   Failed GetDeviceIdAsyncReturnsDeviceId [2 s]   Error Message:
> OneTimeSetUp: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was
> successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
> during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No
> such file or directory) Data:   HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL
> Server   HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer   HelpLink.EvtID: 2
> HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
> HelpLink.LinkId: 20476   ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception :
> No such file or directory
>
> Failed StoreDeviceAsyncStoresTheDeviceIntoDatabase [2 s]   Error
> Message:    OneTimeSetUp: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A
> connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - No such file or directory) Data:
> HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server   HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer
> HelpLink.EvtID: 2   HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink   HelpLink.LinkId: 20476   ---->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No such file or directory
>
> Failed StoreWeatherFactorsAsyncStoresWeatherFactors [2 s]   Error
> Message:    OneTimeSetUp: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A
> connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - No such file or directory) Data:
> HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server   HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer
> HelpLink.EvtID: 2   HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink   HelpLink.LinkId: 20476   ---->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No such file or directory
>
> Test Run Failed. Total tests: 3
> Failed: 3  Total time: 4.5726 Seconds Test run for /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.Api.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebAPI.Api.Tests.Unit.dll
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 16.11.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
> reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... A total of 1 test files
> matched the specified pattern. NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test execution
> started Running all tests in
> /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.BusinessLogic.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebAPI.BusinessLogic.Tests.Unit.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor converted 10 of 10 NUnit test cases   Passed
> StoreDeviceAsyncCallsDevicesRepositoryForDeviceInsertion [110 ms]
> Passed
> StoreDeviceAsyncReturnsOperationResultFailureIfDevicesRepositoryThrowsDbUpdateException
> [37 ms]   Passed
> StoreDeviceAsyncReturnsOperationResultProceededIfSucceeded [< 1 ms]
> Passed StoreDeviceAsyncThrowsArgumentNullExceptionIfDeviceIsNull [17
> ms]   Passed
> StoreWeatherReadingAsyncCallsDevicesRepositoryForDeviceExistence [18
> ms]   Passed
> StoreWeatherReadingAsyncCallsReadingsRepositoryForReadingInsertion [3
> ms]   Passed
> StoreWeatherReadingAsyncReturnsOperationResultFailureIfDevicesRepositoryReturnsOperationResultFailure
> [1 ms]   Passed
> StoreWeatherReadingAsyncReturnsOperationResultFailureIfReadingsRepositoryThrowsDbUpdateException
> [3 ms]   Passed
> StoreWeatherReadingAsyncReturnsOperationResultProceededIfOperationSucceeded
> [1 ms] NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test execution complete NUnit Adapter
> 3.16.1.0: Test execution started Running all tests in /home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.Api.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/net5.0/ET.WebAPI.Api.Tests.Unit.dll
> Passed
> StoreWeatherReadingAsyncThrowsArgumentNullExceptionIfDeviceReadingIsNull
> [1 ms]
>
> Test Run Successful. Total tests: 10
> Passed: 10  Total time: 2.2475 Seconds    NUnit3TestExecutor converted 12 of 12 NUnit test cases   Passed
> StoreDeviceAsyncLogsErrorsIfModelStateIsNotValid [127 ms]   Passed
> StoreDeviceAsyncReturnsAcceptedIfOperationCompletedSuccessfully [37
> ms]   Passed StoreDeviceAsyncReturnsBadRequestIfModelStateIsNotValid
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> StoreDeviceAsyncReturnsInternalServerErrorIfOperationFaulted [32 ms]
> Passed StoreReadingAsyncLogsErrorsIfModelStateIsNotValid [7 ms]
> Passed
> StoreReadingAsyncReturnsAcceptedIfOperationCompletedSuccessfully [2
> ms]   Passed StoreReadingAsyncReturnsBadRequestIfModelStateIsNotValid
> [< 1 ms]   Passed
> StoreReadingAsyncReturnsInternalServerErrorIfOperationFaulted [1 ms]
> Passed ThrowsArgumentNullExceptionIfDeviceIsNull [7 ms] NUnit Adapter
> 3.16.1.0: Test execution complete   Passed ToModelTest [< 1 ms]   Passed ThrowsArgumentNullExceptionIfViewIsNull [< 1 ms]   Passed
> ToModelTest [1 ms]
>
> Test Run Successful. Total tests: 12
> Passed: 12  Total time: 1.1870 Seconds
> 1>Done Building Project "/home/runner/work/ET-Dotnet-API/ET-Dotnet-API/ET.WebAPI.sln" (VSTest
> target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
> 0 Warning(s)
> 0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:08.12

Comment: The error also states "No such file or directory" and "No such file or directory TearDown". Perhaps this is the root cause?

Comment: But mostly it passes right...

Comment: And in those scenarios does that TearDown file or directory exist?

Comment: I assume it MUST exist if action usually succeed

Comment: Use of `2017-CU24-ubuntu-16.04` docker image seems to solve the problem. I'm not really sure what the problem was into. I assume it might be the `isbang/compose-action@v1.0.0` issue. I'll investigate the problem if I'll have some more time